# How to create Fusion Applications Customization Application

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, fusion, user-customization

I have to create a Fusion Applications Customization Application in Jdeveloper. As per the various forums I have to  choose File > New to open the New Gallery. In the New Gallery, select Applications > Fusion Applications Customization Application. But I am not getting this option in jdeveloper installed on my machine. I am using Linux machine for this. Roles that I have used are Oracle Fusion Application developer and Oracle Fusion Application Customization. But Fusion Applications Customization Application option is not coming up in any of the roles.
Could you please let me know on this. Also please let me know the process of creating an application for customization. Any web link or pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The role you should use is "Oracle Fusion Application Developer."  The whitepaper linked in [this post](https://blogs.oracle.com/fadevrel/entry/announcement_how_to_series_explaining) on the Developer Relations blog offers a step-by-step guide on how to get this to work.